# Adding filtering functionalities for records for quick search

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm using two or more drop down lists to filter the results displayed in my JSP page. Now I am only using the `AND` for my database query. For example, I have 2 ddl. Then in my query, I have:

```
Select * from table 
WHERE cityId = ? AND 
categId = ?
```

Now I want to add `ALL` as an option in all my ddl so that when I select the `ALL` option in one ddl, the query would be something like:

```
Select * from table 
WHERE cityId IS NOT NULL AND 
categId = ?
```

How can I implement this using only one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prepare your query according to values are coming.

```
String dropDown1 = request.getParameter("dropDown1");
        String dropDown2 = request.getParameter("dropDown2");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Select * from table where ");
        if(dropDown1 !=null){
            if(dropDown1.equalsIgnoreCase("ALL")){
                builder.append("cityId IS NOT NULL");
            }else{
                builder.append("cityId="+dropDown1);
            }
        }

        if(dropDown2 !=null){
            if(dropDown2.equalsIgnoreCase("ALL")){
                builder.append("and categId IS NOT NULL");
            }else{
                builder.append("and categId="+dropDown2);
            }
        }
        String finalQuery = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Im trying your code but it gives me an error for wrong syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a concatenated string for where condition on the basis of drop-down selection.

e.g. (just logic)

```
whereString = '1';

if POST contain drop1
    whereString += ' AND CONDITION';


if POST contain drop2
    whereString += ' AND CONDITION';
```

Now use whereString in the sql